# Eclipse RCP :- If a view contains huge selection like 4000 objects then applications takes time to show context menus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

We have built a large scale application over eclipse rcp framework. This issue we are facing across the application if large number are objects are selected say 4000 or 5000 objects. In this case, following actions takes time and UI goes in Not Responding state.
1.Select and Right Click Context menu display
2. Keeping selection, change the view and come back to earlier view.
3. Keeping selection, change the application(like excel, word) and come back to view.

My analysis says, the eclipse rcp takes time to evaluate the menu contributions and handlers for the current selected objects. We are also using Property Testers nested inside Iterate expression which I think is taking time to evaluate. Pain is it does the evaluation every time I switch the view and does not cache the result.

I need your opinion:
Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Is there any good way to handle large selection in handlers, menu contributions which will improve the performance.

Thanks in advanced.
~Prasad

Comment: you can try to load them in another thread, like Job and UIJob, from eclipse api

Comment: This evaluation happens from eclipse framework code, how can we wrap it into UIJOB?

Comment: oh, nevermind, I missunderstood your question! sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the main problem are your property testers, because those are evaluated each time something changes visually in your app: new shell (like menu, dialog, wizard etc.) is opened or some panel is expanded/collapsed or you switch perspective or view/editor or you go switch application.

May be as a first step you could try to disable those (or make them dummy and do nothing/or constant action) to see if it affects performance of the application. If it does, then you might think about redesigning your application and replace property testers with, for example combination of `org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider` and `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.IContextService`.

I am not sure, of course, about your real use cases, but here is some idea:

1. Source providers can also be used within plugin.xml as a variable.
2. Then you can register a bunch of contexts (I am not sure, of course, about real use cases, just suggesting here), which can be programmatically activated under some conditions:

   final IContextService contextManager = (IContextService)    activeWorkbenchWindow.getService(IContextService.class);
       contextManager.activateContext("your context id");
3. Another step would be to register context activation listeners:

   ```
       final IContextService contextManager = (IContextService) activeWorkbenchWindow.getService(IContextService.class);
       contextManager.addContextManagerListener(new IContextManagerListener() {

               @Override
               public void contextManagerChanged(ContextManagerEvent contextManagerEvent) {
                   if (!contextManagerEvent.isActiveContextsChanged()) {
                       return;
                   }
                  [process context changes: possibly notify source providers about context changes]
               }
        });
   ```

   4. Make your SourceProvider listen to context changes and refresh state, when something has been actually changed:

      ```
      @Override
      public void contextActivated() {
          fireSourceChanged(getSourcePriority(), refreshState());
      }
      ```

If it is not the case or not possible in you application, then, may be, some other workaround would be to introduce caching in source provider or improve your algorithm performance, by, for example, making some long running operations on parallel with multiple Thread. If you are using Java 8 this should be fairly easy.

Of course there is always a case, that SWT is slow by itself to redraw all the widgets - in this case you may be should look into using alternatives to standard SWT widgets with better performance. For example, using Nattable instead of default SWT/JFace viewers.

I hope this could give you some ideas.

Comment: Alex thanks for help. We also simultaneously working on fixing the property testers. But what I noticed is for each selection Eclipse frameworks evaluates selection 3 times i.e each property tester is evaluated 3 times which looks unnessasary.

Comment: As I've already mentioned: property testers are re-evaluated on "every sneeze" in Eclipse RCP:) so if you debug, you will probably notice, that the main event for such re-evaluation is somewhere, where SWT handles its events and most probably it gets some kind of UI redraw event.